# What is the difference where to put elements in css class?

Tags: css

I can make CSS work, but some things I don't really understand.

Any resource to explain very clearly the differences between:

```
p .example
p.example
.example p
.example.p
```

And:

```
p h1 .example
p h1 .example
.example p h1
.example.p h1
```

Or:

```
p, h1 .example
p, h1 .example
.example p, h1
.example.p, h1
```

ect....

I can see the changes when I experiment, but I don't understand what I'm doing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

p .example

```
<p>Lorem<span class="example">ipsum</span></p>
```

p.example

```
<p class="example">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

.example p

```
<div class="example"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
```

.example.p

```
<div class="example p">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

And:

p h1 .example -> non-standard html

```
<h1 class="example">Title Here</h1><p class="example"></p>
```

p h1 .example -> non-standard html

```
<p class="example"></p><h1 class="example"></h1>
```

.example p h1  -> non-standard html

```
<div class="example"><p>Lorem Ipsum</p><h1>Title Here</h1></div>
```

.example.p h1

```
<div class="example p"><h1>Title Here</h1></div>
```

Or:

p, h1 .example

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p><h1 class="example"></h1>
```

p, h1 .example -> repeated
.example p, h1

```
<div class="example"><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div><h1>Title Here</h1>
```

.example.p, h1

```
<div class="example p">some text here</div><h1>Title Here</h1>
```

Comment: Ok, this is the best answer, can paste in code pen and see it in action;)

Answer (score 5):

Explaining the syntaxes

> white space specifies child nodes any level deep

`p .example` = taking `p` tag as a parent select a element who's class is `example` which can exist under any level under this parent element

`p.example` = select a element which is a `p` tag and has a class `example`

`.example p` = taking element with class `example` as a parent select a element which is `p` tag which can exist under any level under this parent element

`.example.p` = select a element which contains both `example` and `p` as a class (note even `p` is considered as a class as it is used with a `.` operator)

---

`p h1 .example` = start from `p` tag navigate to `h1` tag any level deep and select elements with class `example` which can exist any level deep inside `h1` tag

`p h1.example` = start from `p` tag select a `h1` tag which has a class `example` which can exist any level deep within this `p` tag

`.example p h1` = start from a element with class `example` and navigate to a `p` tag (any level deep) within this element and select all the `h1` tags (any level deep) under this `p` tag

`.example.p h1` = start from a element with both the classes `example` and `p` and select all the `h1` tags(any level deep) under this element

---

> **,** specifies multiple sectors .

Eg: if I want to make all the `p` tags, `div` tags, `span` tags as background red then I can select all of them in one CSS selector and give a specific rule once, like below

```
p, div, span{
 background-color: red;
}
```

`p, h1 .example` = select `p` tag, And select a element with class `example` which is wrapped under `h1` tag any level deep.

By now I am sure you would understand the rest three syntaxes `p, h1 .example` , `.example p, h1` , `.example.p, h1`

Answer (score 3):

FYI on terminology, what you are referring to are called *selectors*.

I'll explain each one:

```
p .example
```

Selects all descendants of a `p` element with class `example`.

```
p.example
```

Selects all `p` elements with class `example`.

```
.example p
```

Selects all `p` descendants of an element with class `example`.

```
.example.p
```

Selects all elements with class `example` and class `p`.

```
p h1 .example
```

Selects all descendants of a `h1` within a `p` with class `example`.

```
p, h1 .example
```

Selects all `p` elements and all descendants of an `h1` with class `example`.

```
.example p h1
```

Selects all `h1` elements that descend from a `p` element that descend from an element with class `example`.

```
.example.p h1
```

Selects all `h1` elements that are descendants of an element with class `example` and class `p`.

```
.example p, h1
```

Selects all `p` elements that are descendants of an element with class `example` and all `h1` elements.

```
.example.p, h1
```

Selects all elements with both class `example` and class `p` and all `h1` elements.

---

## **How to Read CSS**

CSS is difficult to interpret at times. I've found that it's easiest to read it backwards.

Take the first example:

```
p .example
```

Start at the rightmost item `.example`. That means that only elements with class `example` will be selected. Since there is a `p` before that (with a space in between) that "narrows" the selection down to only *descendants* of `p` elements.

In the second example:

```
p.example
```

Again, the rightmost item is `.example`. That means that only elements with class `example` will be selected. Since there is a `p` before that (no space this time) that "narrows" the selection down to only `p` elements with that class.

Here is a sample HTML snippet with a description of which example selects which element:

```
<p class="example">This element will be selected by the second example</p>
<p> <!-- this p element will not be selected by either example -->
    <span class="example">This element will be selected by the first example</span>
</p>
```

**Commas**

Selectors can be comma delimited. Take the following example:

```
p, h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

This selects all `p` tags and all `h1` tags and colors them red.

Comment: `p, h1 ` can be put something like  `select all the p tags, all the h1 tags`

Answer (score 2):

`p .example` -> This means you are targetting class named as "example" acting inside a paragraph(p) tag.

`p.example` -> Generates same result as above.

`.example p` ->  This means you are targetting paragraph(p) tag acting inside a class named "example".

`.example.p` -> This means you are targetting "p" class acting inside a class named "example".

`p h1 .example` -> Targets "example" class inside a "h1" tag which is inside a "p" tag.

`p h1 .example` -> Generates same result as above.

`.example p h1` -> Targets "h1" tag inside a "p" tag which is inside a "example" class.

`.example.p h1` -> Targets "h1" tag inside a "p" class which is inside a "example" class.

`p, h1 .example` -> Here, class "example" inside a "h1" tag will have the same property as "p" tag.

`p, h1 .example` -> Generates same result as above.

`.example p, h1` -> Here, tag "p" inside an "example" tag will have the same property as "h1" tag.

`.example.p, h1` ->  Here, class "p" inside an "example" tag will have the same property as "h1" tag.